# jQuery Selected show span element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down list which has on  with an id of add I would like to .show an  element when the user selects this option.

my jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $('#addContactBox').hide();
        $('#addButton').hide();
            $('select option:selected#add')each.function () {
                $('#addButton').show();
                $('#addButton').click(function(){
                    $('#addContactBox').show();
                });
        });
    });
```

the code does not work can someone help I am pulling my hair out!

Comment: so the "#addButton" is in the select box? I'm a little confused, can you post some html?

Comment: ` $('select option:selected#add')each.function () {`
 you are missing a `"."` before `each`, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#addContactBox').hide();
    $('#addButton').hide();
        $('select option:selected#add').each(function () {
            $('#addButton').show();
            $('#addButton').click(function(){
                $('#addContactBox').show();
            });
    });
});
```

Had a syntax problem with your call to each.

Also, `$('#addButton').click()` doesn't need to be inside the `each`. It's just defining the behavior which is always the same whether or not the button is visible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value of the selected option in the onChange event of the drop down list. You don't need to put an ID on it. Like so:

```
$('#addContactBox').hide();
$('#addButton').hide();
$('#ddl').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Add') {
        $('#addContactBox').show();
        $('#addButton').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $('#addContactBox').hide();
        $('#addButton').hide();
        $('select').change(function () {
            if($('option:selected#add').length>0){
                 $('#addButton').show();
                 $('#addButton').click(function(){
                     $('#addContactBox').show();
                 });
            }
        });
});
```

If i'm not mistaken you are trying to show when the option is selected... maybe like this?